# How to cite my own code in an academic paper?

Tags: publications, citations, code

I’m about to submit a research paper to the Intel STS competition. I am basically finished with everything about my paper, but I need to cite a certain algorithm that I invented in my own paper. I do not want to put it inside the paper because it’s outside the scope of what I talked about in the paper, and besides the paper is already twenty pages so I can’t fit in any more material.

Is it acceptable if I simply post the code to a website like GitHub, and cite the link in my references?

Comment: The Intel STS, as a competition, probably has its own rules for this that are different than norms for academic papers - you will have to contact someone on that side or read their rules. I suspect that, in general, competitions would frown on this - linking to outside documents allows you to put more information in the paper than is permitted, and would also let you change the code after the deadline has passed. But this is only my guess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggested you can create a GitHub repository for your code. There is also the possibility to create a release of your repository. Then you can get a DOI for that release using Zenodo:

[Zenodo How-to](https://guides.github.com/activities/citable-code/)

You can then put that DOI in your paper as reference and do not have the problem with changing code, because the DOI is associated with the specific release.

Comment: Or make a branch/tag for the specific release in Git.